# i want to import a function and arguments from a class which is in other file in python?

Tags: python, function, class, flask, invoke

I am trying to import a function and its arguments which is in another class and in other file. after importing function and arguments here in my file i can get output of those values using that function and then i will be able to render it with html.

```
File Name = CalculationFunc.py

imports ...

class calulations:

 def create_calculation_matrix(self,input:dict):
     calculation_matrix = self.calculation(input)
     few otherfucntions here()
```

Below is Class in which i want to import above function with input dict.

```
File Name = mynewfile.py

from CalculationFunc import calulations
imports ...

 def get_calculation_matrix_from_other_class(self,input:dict):
     calculate_for_render = self.calculation(input)
     data = calculate_for_render 
     return render_html("pages/index.html",data = data )
```

Comment: So what's not working, exactly?  I see where you've created the class, I see where you've imported the class, but I don't see any attempt to actually instantiate the class or call the method you want.

Comment: @IanMcLaird in above code you can see i want to import function self.calculation. 
in my new file.. anyways , please can you guide me .

Comment: So is `calculation` a member of the class `calculations`?  Because it's not defined in the code you've presented.

Answer (score -2):

you could possibly use Tkinter to read the file if it is in the same folder.